# issue with combining csv in batch

Tags: batch-file, csv

I'm using this script to combine multiple csv files all with the same header and all in the same directory. It works well, but it writes the file path to the last line in MASTER.csv, which is an issue when I go to process the data. I'd like to append this batch file so that it no longer outputs the file path, otherwise how would I delete the last line in the MASTER.csv

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set first=1
set fileName="MASTER.csv"
>%fileName% (
  for %%F in (*.csv) do (
    if not "%%F"==%fileName% (
      if defined first (
        type "%%F"
        set "first=" 
      ) else more +1 "%%F"
    )
  )
)
```

Example of the last three lines of MASTER.csv:

```
2014/05/31,23:58:00, 22.0C, 22.33C, 16.17,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,Off
2014/05/31,23:59:00, 21.9C, 22.39C, 16.11,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,Off
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\program\data\enviro\MASTER.csv
```

Comment: I've been unable to duplicate your results (W7 pro)

Answer (score 0):

```
file.bat | find /v "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\program\data\enviro\MASTER.csv" > MASTER.csv
```